# Easier Merge statement

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to write a BQ Merge Query which does something like an upsert. I have a main table(M) and an identical delta table(D) which brings changed records. The merge statement should work like if the keys match it will update all the table fields in the main table with the delta table data and if the keys don't match it will do an insert of the delta table values. I was able to get the Merge statement to work but it seems too long. Is there a shorter way to do this . I have more than 190 columns in my table. Please see the Merge code below.

```
merge zsac_figl01.zsaplikp02 M
using zsac_figl01.zsaplikp02_delta D
on M.VBELN = D.VBELN 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE 
SET 
M.VBELN =  D.VBELN ,
M.ERNAM =  D.ERNAM ,
M.ERZET =  D.ERZET ,
M.ERDAT =  D.ERDAT ,
M.BZIRK =  D.BZIRK ,
M.VSTEL =  D.VSTEL ,
M.VKORG =  D.VKORG ,
M.LFART =  D.LFART ,
M.AUTLF =  D.AUTLF ,
M.KZAZU =  D.KZAZU ,
M.WADAT =  D.WADAT ,
M.LDDAT =  D.LDDAT ,
M.TDDAT =  D.TDDAT ,
M.LFDAT =  D.LFDAT ,
M.KODAT =  D.KODAT ,
M.ABLAD =  D.ABLAD ,
M.INCO1 =  D.INCO1 ,
M.INCO2 =  D.INCO2 ,
M.EXPKZ =  D.EXPKZ ,
M.ROUTE =  D.ROUTE ,
M.FAKSK =  D.FAKSK ,
M.LIFSK =  D.LIFSK ,
M.VBTYP =  D.VBTYP ,
M.KNFAK =  D.KNFAK ,
M.TPQUA =  D.TPQUA ,
M.TPGRP =  D.TPGRP ,
M.LPRIO =  D.LPRIO ,
M.VSBED =  D.VSBED ,
M.KUNNR =  D.KUNNR ,
M.KUNAG =  D.KUNAG ,
M.KDGRP =  D.KDGRP ,
M.STZKL =  D.STZKL ,
M.STZZU =  D.STZZU ,
M.BTGEW =  D.BTGEW ,
M.NTGEW =  D.NTGEW ,
M.GEWEI =  D.GEWEI ,
M.VOLUM =  D.VOLUM ,
M.VOLEH =  D.VOLEH ,
M.ANZPK =  D.ANZPK ,
M.BEROT =  D.BEROT ,
M.LFUHR =  D.LFUHR ,
M.GRULG =  D.GRULG ,
M.LSTEL =  D.LSTEL ,
M.TRAGR =  D.TRAGR ,
M.FKARV =  D.FKARV ,
M.FKDAT =  D.FKDAT ,
M.PERFK =  D.PERFK ,
M.ROUTA =  D.ROUTA ,
M.STAFO =  D.STAFO ,
M.KALSM =  D.KALSM ,
M.KNUMV =  D.KNUMV ,
M.WAERK =  D.WAERK ,
M.VKBUR =  D.VKBUR ,
M.VBEAK =  D.VBEAK ,

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT 
(
VBELN ,
ERNAM ,
ERZET ,
ERDAT ,
BZIRK ,
VSTEL ,
VKORG ,
LFART ,
AUTLF ,
KZAZU ,
WADAT ,
LDDAT ,
TDDAT ,
LFDAT ,
KODAT ,
ABLAD ,
INCO1 ,
INCO2 ,
EXPKZ ,
ROUTE ,
FAKSK ,
LIFSK ,
VBTYP ,
KNFAK ,
TPQUA ,
TPGRP ,
LPRIO ,
VSBED ,
KUNNR ,
KUNAG ,
KDGRP ,
STZKL ,
STZZU ,
BTGEW ,
NTGEW ,
GEWEI ,
VOLUM ,
VOLEH ,
ANZPK ,
BEROT ,
LFUHR ,
GRULG ,
LSTEL ,
TRAGR ,
FKARV ,
FKDAT ,
PERFK ,
ROUTA ,
STAFO ,
KALSM ,
KNUMV ,
WAERK ,
VKBUR ,
VBEAK ,


)

VALUES 

(
D.VBELN,
D.ERNAM,
D.ERZET,
D.ERDAT,
D.BZIRK,
D.VSTEL,
D.VKORG,
D.LFART,
D.AUTLF,
D.KZAZU,
D.WADAT,
D.LDDAT,
D.TDDAT,
D.LFDAT,
D.KODAT,
D.ABLAD,
D.INCO1,
D.INCO2,
D.EXPKZ,
D.ROUTE,
D.FAKSK,
D.LIFSK,
D.VBTYP,
D.KNFAK,
D.TPQUA,
D.TPGRP,
D.LPRIO,
D.VSBED,
D.KUNNR,
D.KUNAG,
D.KDGRP,
D.STZKL,
D.STZZU,
D.BTGEW,
D.NTGEW,
D.GEWEI,
D.VOLUM,
D.VOLEH,
D.ANZPK,
D.BEROT,
D.LFUHR,
D.GRULG,
D.LSTEL,
D.TRAGR,
D.FKARV,
D.FKDAT,
D.PERFK,
D.ROUTA,
D.STAFO,
D.KALSM,
D.KNUMV,
D.WAERK,
D.VKBUR,
D.VBEAK,
D.ZUKRL,
D.VERUR,
D.COMMN,
D.STWAE,
D.STCUR,
D.EXNUM,
D.AENAM,
D.AEDAT,
D.LGNUM,
D.LISPL,
D.VKOIV,
D.VTWIV,
D.SPAIV,
D.FKAIV,
D.PIOIV,
D.FKDIV,
D.KUNIV,
D.KKBER,
D.KNKLI,
D.GRUPP,
D.SBGRP,
D.CTLPC,
D.CMWAE,
D.AMTBL,
D.BOLNR,
D.LIFNR,
D.TRATY,
D.TRAID,
D.CMFRE,
D.CMNGV,
D.XABLN,
D.BLDAT,
D.WADAT_IST,
D.TRSPG,
D.TPSID,
D.LIFEX,
D.TERNR,
D.KALSM_CH,
D.KLIEF,
D.KALSP,
D.KNUMP,
D.NETWR,
D.AULWE,
D.WERKS,
D.LCNUM,
D.ABSSC,
D.KOUHR,
D.TDUHR,
D.LDUHR,
D.WAUHR,
D.LGTOR,
D.LGBZO,
D.AKWAE,
D.AKKUR,
D.AKPRZ,
D.PROLI,
D.XBLNR,
D.HANDLE,
D.TSEGFL,
D.TSEGTP,
D.TZONIS,
D.TZONRC,
D.CONT_DG,
D.VERURSYS,
D.KZWAB,
D.VLSTK,
D.TCODE,
D.VSART,
D.TRMTYP,
D.SDABW,
D.VBUND,
D.XWOFF,
D.DIRTA,
D.PRVBE,
D.FOLAR,
D.PODAT,
D.POTIM,
D.VGANZ,
D.IMWRK,
D.SPE_LOEKZ,
D.SPE_LOC_SEQ,
D.SPE_ACC_APP_STS,
D.SPE_SHP_INF_STS,
D.SPE_RET_CANC,
D.SPE_WAUHR_IST,
D.SPE_WAZONE_IST,
D.SPE_REV_VLSTK,
D.SPE_LE_SCENARIO,
D.SPE_ORIG_SYS,
D.SPE_CHNG_SYS,
D.SPE_GEOROUTE,
D.SPE_GEOROUTEIND,
D.SPE_CARRIER_IND,
D.SPE_GTS_REL,
D.SPE_GTS_RT_CDE,
D.SPE_REL_TMSTMP,
D.SPE_UNIT_SYSTEM,
D.SPE_INV_BFR_GI,
D.SPE_QI_STATUS,
D.SPE_RED_IND,
D.SAKES,
D.SPE_LIFEX_TYPE,
D.SPE_TTYPE,
D.SPE_PRO_NUMBER,
D.LOC_GUID,
D.SPE_BILLING_IND,
D.PRINTER_PROFILE,
D.MSR_ACTIVE,
D.PRTNR,
D.STGE_LOC_CHANGE,
D.TM_CTRL_KEY,
D.DLV_SPLIT_INITIA,
D.DLV_VERSION,
D.BEV1_LULEINH,
D.BEV1_RPFAESS,
D.BEV1_RPKIST,
D.BEV1_RPCONT,
D.BEV1_RPSONST,
D.BEV1_RPFLGNR,
D.BORGR_GRP,
D.ZLAND1,
D.ZZTVGW,
D.ZZVTW,
D.ZZFRGEW,
D.ZZANZPAL,
D.ZZKDKG1,
D.ZZVOLLPAL
)`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if the keys match it will update all the table fields in the main table with the delta table data and if the keys don't match it will do an insert of the delta table values

Based on above I assume the schema of main and delta table are identical
So, you can explore option of doing DELETE and INSERT instead of UPDATE and INSERT

Something like

```
DELETE zsac_figl01.zsaplikp02
WHERE VBELN IN (SELECT VBELN FROM zsac_figl01.zsaplikp02_delta)
```

And then (note - [Omitting column names](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#omitting_column_names) is in Beta since June 3, 2019, so you should try )

```
INSERT zsac_figl01.zsaplikp02
SELECT * FROM zsac_figl01.zsaplikp02_delta
```